# I need to create an Insert pass-through query to SQL Server in Access VBA

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, insert, connection

I need to create a pass-through query to SQL Server. I have a functioning pass-through query which only runs from the navigation bar or query design in Access, and it only creates a single record. I have dozens of records to insert into a SQL Server table based on values in an Access table. Thus, I need to loop through the Access table in code, and for each record there create the SQL string and execute it. I've got the looping working, just need the proper code to connect to the SQL database and execute the SQL string. Here's the ODBC Connect String in the pass-through query that works, with the PW and DB starred out: "ODBC;DSN=jobboss32; UID=support; PWD=****;DATABASE=****". The code below gives a Data Type Conversion Error.

```
Dim strFuturePTOSource, strPassThruInsert, strEmpName, strPTODate, strUpdated As String
Dim datPTODate As Date, lngPTOHours As Long
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset, q As QueryDef

    strFuturePTOSource = "qryROBERT"    'temporary data set to test, change to actual after working
    rs.Open strFuturePTOSource, CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
    With rs
        If Not .BOF And Not .EOF Then
            .MoveLast
            .MoveFirst

            While (Not .EOF)
                strEmpName = rs.Fields("EmpName")
                strEmpName = "'" & strEmpName & "', "
                datPTODate = rs.Fields("PTODate")
                strPTODate = "'" & Format(datPTODate, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "'"
                lngPTOHours = rs.Fields("PTOHrs") * 60
                strUpdated = "'" & Format(Now(), "mm/dd/yyyy") & "'"
                strPassThruInsert = "INSERT INTO Attendance (Attendance, Employee, Work_Date, Regular_Minutes, Attendance_Type, Lock_Times, Source, Last_Updated) VALUES (NewID(), "
                strPassThruInsert = strPassThruInsert & strEmpName & strPTODate & ",lngPTOHours,2,-1,0, '" & Now() & "');"
                Set q = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", strPassThruInsert)
                CurrentDb.QueryDefs(q).Execute
                .MoveNext
            Wend
        End If
        .Close
    End With
```

Comment: 1) Link the SQL server table in Access, 2) Create an INSERT query (in Access) where you pass only the ID as parameter, 3) Loop through the recordset, call the query and pass  the ID. If no option to link, consider using an ADODB Command. Your solution above is very messy.

Comment: If you want to write code that writes tsql, then you need to see the statement you attempt to execute. So do that - in the debugger, stop on the line before you execute it and examine the complete statement and figure out why it generates that error.

Comment: What happens if you replace `CurrentDb.QueryDefs(q).Execute` with just `q.Execute`?  Do you get a different error?

Comment: Among other issues, not concatenating variable lngPTOHours.

Comment: Good catch on concantenating lngPTOHours. Still getting conversion error with this sSQL statement: INSERT INTO Attendance (Attendance, Employee, Work_Date, Regular_Minutes, Attendance_Type, Lock_Times, Source, Last_Updated) VALUES (NewID(), 'PERKR', '12/28/2020',600,2, -1, 0, '5/19/2020 1:20:31 PM');. For comparison here's the pass-through SQL that does work. INSERT INTO Attendance (Attendance, Employee, Work_Date, Regular_Minutes, Attendance_Type, Lock_Times, Source, Last_Updated) VALUES (NewID(), 'PERKR', '12/28/2020',600,2,-1,0,GetDate()); GetDate() is T-SQL & won't compile in Access.

Comment: Hans, getting closer. q.Execute doesn't cause a conversion error, but says NewID() is an undefined function. That suggests to me that how I've written it, it is trying to execute it as a native Access query instead of a pass-through query to SQL Server.

Comment: Evharisto Kostas. I would do this but the SQL Server table requires a GUID field and it can't be generated in Access.

Answer (score 1):

First, you not given ANY valid reason to insert with a pass-through query.

And in fact, since EACH insert will be a 100% and separate and “discrete” insert?

Well, the time for the query processor to setup, parse the syntax, and do the insert?

Well, you not achieve ANY gains in performance, and in fact it will run no faster than a plain Jane and standard insert using DAO recodsets.

As a result:
You are knowingly as a developer wasting all kinds of time pursuing this approach and this is AFTER having been given this advice on places such as UA.

And if you knowingly are wasting developer time, and seeking an approach that costs more developer time, does not speed up your insets, then you are with full knowledge seeking an approach that costs more time, and more resources than necessary.

I suppose if you are paying for this time, and don’t care, or perhaps you are doing this as a learning exercise, then fine. But as for a working solution, the approach does not make sense, takes more code and time to develop and fix, and you are doing this will full knowledge as to the increased cost and time without any benefits I can see, or think of.

So then this begs the question?
Why would you attempt a solution will FULL knowledge that costs more time, costs more effort, and does not increase performance?
You do not given any reason as to the added benefits of this approach.

The following code is far less, far more simple, will run FASTER than your given approach. And FAR better is the date conversions that you have (are WRONG), are a non-issue.

So, you have to cook up a VERY good reason as to WHY you are perusing this course of action when:

It will not run faster than using the code I post here
(In fact, such a PT     query will run slower – and by A WIDE margin).

You have errors in your date formats – you have to use ISO sql server format
(But, if you use ODBC and let the record set do the translation, then ZERO formatting and ZERO re-formatting of the date and date time values you have is NOT required).

So, until such time you explain why you are willing with full knowledge to write more code, cost more time, and cook up a solution that wastes time, and will not run faster?

Then I see little if any reason to pursue your approach?, right?

So, you need to come up with a VERY good reason as to why you are insisting on this pass-through query approach, and an approach that will run NOT run faster than what I am posting here... And in fact, as I point out, the posted solution will run MUCH faster. (Not I said a wee bit faster – but MUCH faster – in fact on a multiple order (not %, but factors of times faster). I can explain WHY this is the case (better speed) if you are wondering why.

In the meantime, you are going to have to figure out how to sleep with full knowledge of pursuing  a solution that is going to cost more in developer time, and not yield any benefits in terms of speed, or even maintenance and writing of such code.

This code eliminates the date error conversions you have,  and WILL RUN faster than your posted code and solution:

```
Dim strFuturePTOSource  As String

Dim rstFrom             As DAO.Recordset  ' from table
Dim rstTo               As DAO.Recordset  ' SQL server linked table.

Set rstFrom = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("qryROBERT", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
Set rstTo = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Attendance", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)

Do While rstFrom.EOF = False
   With rstTo
      .AddNew
      !Attendance = NewID()
      !Employee = rstFrom!EmpName
      !Work_Date = rstFrom!PTODate
      !Regular_Minutes = 600
      !Attendance_Type = 2
      !Lock_Times = -1
      !Source = 0
      !Last_UPdated = Now
      .Update
   End With
   rstFrom.MoveNext
Loop
rstTo.Close
rstFrom.Close
```

## Edit

Given that the poster HAS made a good case that a PT query is to be used?

then this code should work:

We assume that you ALREADY created a working PT query. (and it has return records set = false). I tend to create ONE PT query in Access, and then any and all places in code can re-use that PT query at well. Also if NewID() is a scalar function (t-sql), as noted, it MUST be prefixed with dbo. So, we have to use dbo.NewID()

So, the code that is "close" or that I would suggest is this:

```
Dim rs         As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL     As String
Dim strSQLS    As String

strSQLS = "INSERT INTO Attendance (Attendance, Employee, Work_Date, Regular_Minutes, " & _
         "Attendance_Type, Lock_Times, Source, Last_Updated) " & _
         "VALUES (dbo.NewID(),"


Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("qryROBERT")

With rs

  Do While .EOF = False
  
     strSQL = strSQLS
     
     strSQL = strSQL & qu(!EmpName) & "," & quDate(!PTODate) & _
              "," & quDate(Date) & "," & (!PTOHrs * 60) & ",2,-1,0," & quDate(Now())
              
     With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("MyPassQuery")
        .SQL = strSQL
        .Execute
     End With
  
     .MoveNext
  Loop
  rs.Close
  
End With
```

In addtion to the above, I used two helper functions to format the date, as it is a pain to do this "in-line" code, so, I have qu() (for strings), and qudate() for dates.

```
Public Function qudate(myDate As Variant) As String

  ' returns a formatted string of date, ISO format, for sql sesrver.
  ' format is yyyy-mm-dd regardless of local date settings

  If IsNull(myDate) = True Then
     qudate = ""
  Else
     ' use ISO date format
     qudate = "'" & Format(myDate, "yyyy-mm-dd HH:NN:SS") & "'"
  End If

End Function
```

And our qu() function

```
Function quS(vText As Variant) As String
  
  ' takes a string and surrounds it with single quotes
  
  If IsNull(vText) = False Then
     If InStr(vText, Chr(34)) > 0 Then
        vText = Replace(CStr(vText), Chr(34), "'")
     End If
  End If

  quS = "'" & vText & "'"
  
End Function
```

## Edit 2

So, the steps are:
From sql studio, get a example working that inserts data. Once you have a working  insert command, then take that same (and known) working command and cut + paste it into an access query - but just ensure that the query on the Access side is created and set as pass-though. Once again, test running this PT query. If the existing sql worked in SSMS, then it will work in Access 100% exactly with the SAME query. Once that is working?

so, whatever name you gave this query is what you use in place of MyPassQuery. You can give it any name you want, but you have to use the correct (same) name in your VBA code that going to use/set the sql for that PT query. So, each loop run will in fact overwrite what is in the query, and then you do the .Execute to run it.

Well, then you run your code. And on this line for testing?

```
.SQL = strSQL
```

Do this:

```
debug.print strSQL
.SQL = strSQL
```

So, as you single step though that code, the sql the VBA is creating will have to match the known working sql you had. So, if the string output has any syntax errors or does not look 100% the same as that known working sql? Well, then you have to tweak the VBA code until such time it spits out the SAME sql string that you know works.

Comment: Thanks Albert. I do have to do the Insert. Only a couple of times each year ~150 records will be inserted into the SQL Server database, and the rest of the time only 4 or 5 a day, so efficiency isn't a concern. The main reason I can't use a standard Access query or code to add records to the linked SQL Server table is that it requires GUID indices, and those can't be generated in Access. SQL Server generates those itself when it receives the T-SQL statement and the NewID() function creates the GUID index. Thus the loop and need to generate the SQL and execute it each time in the loop. Thanks+

Comment: Ok, all I was perhaps harsh, but you simply had to make a case as to why you need the PT query. And if NewID() is a T-SQL function, then you will likey need a PT query. And if NewID() is a custom t-sql function (a scaler function), the you MUST prefix it with DBO.NewID().  Given this info - I'll do a edit to my above post.

Comment: And I see that NewID() is NOT a scaler function, but is a built in one. If that was already specifed as a default value for the table then you should be able to remove NewID() 100% from above. If it is not the default, then include it as per above code, but remove the dbo.prefix.

Comment: Getting closer. Right now it's stopped at      With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("MyPassQuery").

Comment: See my edit #2 - you have to create a pass-though query, and use that name. It could be called ZooZoo or whatever. In my example I called it MyPassQuery"), but at the end of the day you have to use a valid and ALREADY existing PT query that you created.

Comment: Please check the strSQL. It's evaluating as INSERT INTO Attendance (Attendance, Employee, Work_Date, Regular_Minutes, Attendance_Type, Lock_Times, Source, Last_Updated) VALUES (dbo.NewID(),'PERKR','2020-12-28 00:00:00','2020-05-20 00:00:00',600,2,-1,0,'2020-05-20 16:31:02' which seems to have an extra date, and the form of the first date variable the table is expecting is '12/28/2020' if that matters. The ddmmyy format is US based as is the SQL Server db. Should I remove the qudate(date) and single quotes on both sides?

Comment: Here's how I modified the strSQL:
     strSQL = strSQL & quS(!EmpName) & "," & qudate(!PTODate) & _
              ", " & (!PTOHrs * 60) & ",2,-1,0," & qudate(Now()) & ");"
When I run now I get the error 3146 ODBC call failed.

Comment: SUCCESS! Thanks to your genius! Here's the two lines I changed:
         "VALUES (NewID(),"
              ", " & (!PTOHrs * 60) & ",2,-1,0," & qudate(Now()) & ");"
Can you tell me the purpose of With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("ptqryPostPTORecord") and why that makes it work? Does it have something to do with the ODBC connect string and other parameters in that query?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: It just a code saving step. So, say if you want a report based on a PT query? Then set the sql of the PT query in code, and on the next line just launch the report (which is based on that PT query). So, using a PT query this way lets you on the fly in VBA code stuff in any t-sql command or sql you want. You can do all the hoops of setting up say ADO and setting up the connection, but it simply less code and hassle to use a existing and already working PT query with a known working connection. So this approach just eliminates having to mess and setup a connection strings in your VBA code.

Comment: Is there a way to give you a great rating or thumbs up? If not, thanks again.

Comment: No worries - someone upvoted this . At least you stuck to your guns and still wanted a solution. And at the end of the day? Yes, due to the NewID(), then you quite much did need a PT query - so, our (my) original suggestion to not use PT query was incorrect anyway. All in all - you have a good "template" and workable approach for such types of problems in the future.